# Google Spreadsheet get address that cell points to

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have an spreadsheet like the table below

```
+---+-----------------+-----+--------------------------------+
|   |        A        |  B  |               C                |
+---+-----------------+-----+--------------------------------+
| 1 | This is my text | =A1 | 'This should be the value "A1" |
+---+-----------------+-----+--------------------------------+
```

where `A1` is the text "This is my text", and `B1` is the function `=A1`. I need a function for `C1` that gives me the text `A1`, because that's the cell that `B1` points to. [INDEX](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_function.php) and [INDIRECT](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) do not seem to give me what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

I know of no Google Spreadsheet function which returns the formula of a cell, but you can define a custom function using the Script Editor. Define a custom function **formula** which returns the formula of a cell, given the row and column number of the cell. Then use the custom function in the formula of cell C1. The formula of cell C1 would contain:

```
=formula(1,2)
```

And this would cause the value of cell C1 to be the string:

```
"=A1"
```

A couple of useful refinements to the formula in cell C1. First, calculate the row and column from a cell reference using the `row()` and `column()` functions:

```
=formula( row(B1) , column(B1) )
```

Second, trim off the `=` (which, according to your problem statement, you do not want):

```
=mid( formula(row(B1),column(B1)) , 2 , 9999 )
```

To define the function **formula**, go to Tools, Script Editor, and enter the following script:

```
function formula(r,c) {
  return SpreadsheetApp . getActiveSheet() . getRange(r,c) . getFormula() ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been like nine years since this question was asked, but since there is only one response and it starts out with "I know of no Google Spreadsheet function which returns the formula of a cell", I figured I'd go ahead and answer this since there is, in fact, a function that returns the formula of a cell.

=FORMULATEXT([CELL])

This will do exactly as it says and return the text of the formula within that cell.  From there you can use the standard string functions LEFT, RIGHT, MID to extract what you want out of it.